# Create a button using image instead of background color?

Tags: html, css, button, opacity

Ok, so I am attempting to make a button but instead of using a fill color and changing the color on :hover I want to use an image as the background and change its opacity on :hover.

Here is a jsfiddle to sort of see what I am trying to do. The first button is the template im going off of, but its too boring for my taste.

I can create a button with the image as the background but when I set and change the opacity it obviously changes this for all child elements and I need the text to be unaffected. I also need it to be response with a 100% width so that it can resize with a containing grid on my website.

I have tried to create a container div that I placed the link text and an img src and tried to do position:absolute and position/relative but this breaks the container div. Im sure I am just overlooking something simple and have just been thinking about it for too long.

Essentially, I am having trouble stacking multiple elements in container div so I can target the :hover for the image and nothing else.

Any help is appreciated!!

UPDATE:

I figured out how to get what I was wanting, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/6EMNM/

HTML

```
<div class="cma-button-wrapper">
<a href="#"><div class="cma-button-header">Header Text</div>
<div class="cma-button">
    <img src="http://breadedcat.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cat-breading-tutorial-004.jpg" />
    <p class="title">Bread Cat!</p></a>
</div></div>
```

CSS

```
.cma-button-wrapper {
    width:250px;
    }

.cma-button-wrapper img:hover  {
    opacity:.6;
    }


.cma-button-wrapper a{
    text-decoration:none;
    }
.cma-button a{
    /* force the div to properly contain the floated images: */
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cma-button img {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: .2;
}
/*.cma-button img:hover {
    opacity: .3;

}*/

.cma-button .title {
    font-size:1.9em;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top:10%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}
.cma-button a {
    color:#000;
    }

.cma-button-header {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: light;
    font-size:.9em;
    padding:.4em;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#FF7300;
    }
```

This is close but how do I make it so that when you mouse over any child element of .cma-button-wrapper the img changes opacity but nothing else. Is this possible with pure CSS or do I need javascript? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the question? You clearly have an idea of how to address the question in the title. Be specific in the title and in the question itself. How does the code and jsfiddle demonstrate the problem you have? And where are the buttons? If you use proper button elements instead of `img` elements, as you should, you will have a somewhat different problem.

Comment: I guess I am trying to figure out how to create a stack of divs so that I can have multiple elements in my button that are all editable individually without needed to use two seperate images but the only way I know how to do that is to use relative and absolute positioning but that seems to break any responsiveness because it wont stay within a container div.

Comment: I’m afraid the clarification is even more obscure than the question. Edtable by whom? What do *you* mean by “responsiveness”, and how does the jsfiddle demonstrate that?

Comment: I figured it out. Sorry for the confusion, I wasnt sure how to ask how to do what I was trying to do. But Ive come along another snag that I am posting below.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 ways and it will work with every browser:

```
.button-image:hover {
 -khtml-opacity:.50; 
 -moz-opacity:.50; 
 -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=50)";
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
  opacity:.50; 
}
```

Or you can create 2 images in photoshop. One "button_image.png" And one "button_image_hover.png" with transparency you want. Should be PNG.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Just update your previous answer, there's no need to post a new one.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do the opacity but my issue is that the divs wont stack on each other using 100% width.